# Enabling Lazy Initialization Breaks Kafka Listeners Using Spring Cloud Kafka Binder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, lazy-evaluation, boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot 3 application where I've been trying to optimize startup times by enabling **lazy initialization**. However, after making this change, I've encountered an issue with Kafka listeners. Specifically, the listeners stop receiving messages.

I attempted to explicitly set the `@Lazy(false)` annotation on the Kafka listener components, this hasn't resolved the problem. While it appears that the listener beans are created at startup *(as expected with @Lazy(false))*, they still do not receive any messages from Kafka.

I use **Spring Boot 3.2.2** and I load my Kafka listeners from the property file like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      allowOverride: true
      overrideNone: true
      overrideSystemProperties: false
    function:
      definition: >-
        listenExample;
    stream:
      bindings:
        listenExample-in-0:
          destination: example-topic
          group: example-group
          consumer:
            use-native-decoding: true
      kafka:
        bindings:
          listenExample-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: example-error-topic
              dlqPartitions: 1
```

The component:

```
@Component("listenExample")
@Lazy(false)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class ExampleListener implements Consumer<Message<String>> {

    @Override
    public void accept(Message<String> message) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!